# Store value is getting lost on page refresh when using localStorage

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use the localstorage to store value in browser but on page refresh, it's getting lost.
No idea, why! Because, as per the official documentation of localstorage, it has no expiry date.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: check if you removeitem on pageload, otherwise localstore will not remove on page load.

Comment: Provide some code to reproduce the issue. How will we know what you are doing ?

Comment: Need more information + code that you have tried :)

Comment: Just setting the value using localStorage on checkbox checked
window.localStorage.setItem("sampleCheckbox", true);